# How to find Instagram developer support?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am thinking on a project that uses insta APIs but when I signup for instagramdeveloper account I have some kinda issue with it. I cannot find a button to create new Client and when I hit Manage client button this is what I got:

[image: here]

when I hit Registration Disabled button Nothing Happens. Is that mean am I ban from an Instagram developer account? please note I haven't created any kind of Client ID since I created an Instagram developer account.

OR was this some kinda bug? 
How can I report my issue to the Instagram support team?
your suggestions are appreciated:)

Comment: I am also seeing "Registration Disabled". Only difference is i already have one client, but i want to create a new one.

Comment: I report this issue to Instagram by going through mobile app and they fixed the problem.

Comment: @ns789 how long Instagram fix your problem after you sent report?

Comment: just within in 24hr or maybe less

Comment: any notification for the response? or we just frequently check Instagram developer website?

Comment: no, notification in this case, you have to check the site manually

Comment: ok thank you, but until now I haven't gotten any changes in my Instagram Developer website :'(

Comment: this API is desperate switch to new https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know why my registration button is disabled too. Maybe Instagram api update. But I realize this guide and It works for me. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started

Updated :

In my case, i am using webview in android. So, below is the example code :
(Ignore the Dialog, you can implement only webview and its onpagefinished method)

```
    public class AuthenticationDialog extends Dialog {
        private String TAG = AuthenticationDialog.class.getSimpleName();
        private AuthenticationListener listener;
        private Context context;
        private WebView webView;

        private final String url = "https://api.instagram.com/" + "oauth/authorize/?app_id=" +
                getResources().getString(R.string.app_id)
                + "&redirect_uri="
                + getResources().getString(R.string.redirect_url)
                + "&response_type=code"
                + "&scope=user_profile,user_media";

        public AuthenticationDialog(@NonNull Context context, AuthenticationListener listener) {
            super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

            this.context = context;
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.auth_dialog);
            this.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            initializeWebView();
        }

        private void initializeWebView() {
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            Log.d(TAG, "url: " + url);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                String access_token;
                boolean authComplete;

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPageStarted called");
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished called " + url);
                    if (url.contains("?code=") && !authComplete) {
                        Log.d(TAG, " inside access_token");
                        access_token = url;
                        //get the whole token after "=" sign
                        access_token = access_token.replace("https://www.instagram.com/?code=","");
                        access_token = access_token.replace("#_","");
                        Log.d(TAG, "token: " + access_token);
                        authComplete = true;
                        listener.onTokenReceived(access_token);
                        webView.loadUrl("https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/");

                        dismiss();
                    } else if (url.contains("?error")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "getting error fetching access token");
                        dismiss();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "outside both" + url.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting the error on Step 4: Authenticate the Test User in that document. Can you explain how you did that?

Comment: You can open that link in any browser or webview if you are using android

Comment: Now I fixed that one. But getting some error on Step 5: Exchange the Code for a Token. Like this -> {
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Matching code was not found or was already used"
} Is there any other solution to get user id and access token in instagram? Kindly help me on this.

Comment: i am not sure about the problem, are you generate access token by postman? please check your code not include any "#_" character.

Comment: I am also facing same problem {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Matching code was not found or was already used"}

Comment: POST https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
 D/OkHttp: app_id="app id"&app_secret="App secret"&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8081%252F&code=AQCDTDeDxUrpl_pqQRit2lL3i_OITTknGdIyUyQAOylu-SqSPz-t2pMlDNTAS8SFEeaJlyKWGC8BScFKXOZY5M9dgFMjd-GSfw5zGAgU6IsMJYOLNA74Dd8-dOTiM7X18Rmu6ZWTG-lHg7pcI8Tmzaa2e4XASvuhTfPdGKuyWLPD2c8F2zvJOnLNprDC4a3WEcI9Xi2FA6BAC8-KyYUoMAv9U3a1VhbyGB2gmEPr0SmTFw
 D/OkHttp: --> END POST

Comment: Maybe you can replace redirect uri to "https://www.instagram.com/". i am not sure it will work. But its like you are using localhost, i dont know it works or not if redirect uri is localhost.

Answer (score 3):

It's really hard to find Instagram customer support direct interact whenever you are in trouble with some sort of APIs like I have Because the same problem faces my self. honestly https://help.instagram.com not help me a lot because it's quite confusing to  find the support interact.

To report the issue you face to Instagram customer support team can be done:

**Through Instagram Android Application**

Explain your exact problem to report a problem to ICS.
[image: here]

And this is how I fix my problem and my registration new client button is back:)

[image: here]

Answer (score 2):

After a week ago I posted my first answer, but then I got a message on my Instagram developer dashboard.

[image: here]

And My **New registration** button **disabled** again because in the favor of new [Instagram Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api).

[image: here]

Comment: So what is the new solution?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api this is the solution