# Instagram new client registration disabled

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api, umbraco7

I'm using SkyBrud (https://social.skybrud.dk/instagram/) and usually setup Instagram with this API within an Umbraco/ASP .net site. The site would display images from Instagram to my site, which is connected via API keys generated on Instagram and using them in the service i just linked.

Recently i decided to create a new account (Insta) in order to obtain some Instagram API keys. After the first step i see "**Registration Disabled**" and no way to continue to obtain the API keys.

According to the site above, i got the vision its no longer being supported. I then came across [How to find Instagram developer support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343755/how-to-find-instagram-developer-support) with similar issues but some went through a mobile app to get it sorted which i thought was strange and the other answers related to Android so dont think it applies to me.

I then read other links which are pointing to Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started but i dont know if this step is the right step in getting the existing functionality working up and quickly?

There's just too directions so im not to sure which way to go to get the API?

Comment: _What_ existing functionality? Describe what you need, instead of just pointing to some external service.

Comment: Oh i thought it would have been obvious. I want to display images on my site from Instagram. Which is what used to happen

Comment: You’ll have to use the new API Facebook provides then. But that will only work, if you have a “professional” account on IG (Business or Creator) - for normal user accounts, there is no replacement API.

Comment: Ok. If i convert the account to a free business account  (https://help.instagram.com/502981923235522?helpref=faq_content) then it would generate the API keys to use or would this be a complete re-write and anything i had existing would no longer work?

Comment: No, those are two completely different APIs - so it is more likely going to be a complete rewrite.

Comment: Finally, any existing APIs keys I have which work would no longer work as of next year, if I've read this correctly. They too would need a business account etc? If you want to add your comments as an answer I will mark them as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The old Instagram API is in the process of being shut down by Facebook; You’ll have to use the new API Facebook provides, for anything that you want to build now.

The new API is only available for “professional” accounts on IG (Business or Creator) though - for normal user accounts, there is no replacement API.

Any existing tokens you have for the old API should probably keep working, until they shut it down completely.

The APIs are different in almost anything, so what code you currently have, will probably need a larger rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Further to 04FS's answer, the [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/) is now available for all accounts.